# Can I configure default verbosity in pycharm setting? If so where can I setup that?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, pytest

Now I'm using terminals to achieve specific verbosity for Pytest framework as below,

[image]

I'm looking for default options/settings in pycharm to set my verbosity level as "2" instead of feeding in terminals every time.

Specifications are:

**Python 38**

**Pycharm 2020.3**

**Pytest 6.2.2**

Answer (score 1):

If you've got `pytest` set up as your default test framework you can modify the test configuration.

When running your test, click on that `wrench` icon, on the left. It says `Modify Run Configuration`.

[image]

Then, in the context window go to `Additional Arguments` and type your `pytest` args. For example:

[image]

Finally, when you run the tests, you should see something along the way of:

> Launching pytest with arguments -v --tb=long

[image]

Comment: I updated the settings as below and no change in response i.e still getting F for failure and green dot for pass case in terminal.

Comment: How can i share my screenshot in comments?

Comment: You can't share a screenshot in the comments. You can add one to the question. How are you running your tests? With PyCharm or from the terminal?